# Visual Studio 2010 - стандартное приложение C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Как сделать, чтобы Visual Studio 2010 при создании нового консольного приложения C++ генерировала метод main, а не _tmain?

Comment: перейти на компилятор, который поддерживает стандарт либо просто перестать париться. Это ведь майкрософт. Есть конечно вариант сделать свой шаблон.

Comment: А чем это вам мешает? Переименуйте в main и замените tchar на char, делов-то.

Comment: Ничем не мешает. Просто думал, что есть какая-то опция для выбора вида точки входа в приложение.

Comment: @DarkGenius: У MSVC точкой входа будет функция `main`, `wmain`, `WinMain` или `_tmain`, смотря какую вы напишете. [Вот](/questions/213830/) обсуждение по теме. Никакой специальной опции не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Visual Studio используются шаблоны, которые можно создавать, редактировать и настраивать по своему желанию. Можно и проще, что бы не переделывать стандартный шаблон и лезть в дебри VS, создать свой шаблон с нужной структурой. Информация по теме(там есть тема "Создание шаблонов проектов"):
[Справочник по шаблонам](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/ms247064(v=vs.100).aspx), [Практическое руководство. Создание шаблонов проектов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.100).aspx)

Стандартные шаблоны располагаются в папке: %Visual Studio path%\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates. Для Visual studio 2010 они будут упакованы в zip файлы, которые можно распаковать и отредактировать файлы шаблона по своему усмотрению. 
[How to: Update Existing Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx)